The clear button overlaps the placeholder
My clear button overlaps the placeholder:

Have you ever had this problem?
I'm using the bootstrap5 theme for select2.
Everything else works.
It's just this button that's causing the problem.
Thanks.


$('#selectMySearch').select2({
  theme: "bootstrap-5",
  width: "300px",
  placeholder: $(this).data('placeholder'),
  closeOnSelect: false,
  allowClear: true,
});
<select class="form-select" id="selectMySearch" data-placeholder="Recherches enregistrées ">
  <option></option>
  <option>Test1</option>
  <option>Test2</option>
</select>


<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.11.3/font/bootstrap-icons.min.css" />

<!-- Styles -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2-bootstrap-5-theme@1.3.0/dist/select2-bootstrap-5-theme.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/public/css/main.css">

<!-- DataTables CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.5/css/dataTables.bootstrap5.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.7.1/css/buttons.bootstrap5.min.css">

<!-- Or for RTL support -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2-bootstrap-5-theme@1.3.0/dist/select2-bootstrap-5-theme.rtl.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.7.1/css/buttons.bootstrap5.min.css">

<!-- Scripts -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.7.0/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/axios@1/dist/axios.min.js"></script>


<!-- DataTables JS -->
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.6/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.7.1/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.6/js/dataTables.bootstrap5.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.7.1/js/buttons.bootstrap5.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.2.2/jszip.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.7.1/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/2.3.6/js/buttons.colVis.min.js"></script>




Please include all of the relevant <script> and <link css that you're using.  Could be a version mismatch or a missing css.  See [mcve]

I made you a snippet. Please make it a [mcve]

Thanks for this help. The example is set.
Thank you very much.

@TheoB do this and it will work for you: https://prnt.sc/05IJWR7LqxrK

Thanks. It now works. Thank you very much.

@TheoB  I have added the same as an answer. Please check and consider marking it if worked.

There are 2 issue:
a) For same class CSS added twice having some common and some different parameters.It's not the correct practic.Add all into one place untill you need to separate it for different devices screen. (Although Browser smart enough to over-write them by themselves)
b) left:2.25 rem is the culprit here. Remove it and you are good to go.
Solution: https://prnt.sc/05IJWR7LqxrK


$('#selectMySearch').select2({
  theme: "bootstrap-5",
  width: "300px",
  placeholder: $(this).data('placeholder'),
  closeOnSelect: false,
  allowClear: true,
});
.select2-container--bootstrap-5 .select2-selection--multiple .select2-selection__clear, .select2-container--bootstrap-5 .select2-selection--single .select2-selection__clear {
    left: unset !important;
}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.11.3/font/bootstrap-icons.min.css" />

<!-- Styles -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2-bootstrap-5-theme@1.3.0/dist/select2-bootstrap-5-theme.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/public/css/main.css">

<!-- DataTables CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.5/css/dataTables.bootstrap5.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.7.1/css/buttons.bootstrap5.min.css">

<!-- Or for RTL support -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2-bootstrap-5-theme@1.3.0/dist/select2-bootstrap-5-theme.rtl.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.7.1/css/buttons.bootstrap5.min.css">

<!-- Scripts -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.7.0/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/axios@1/dist/axios.min.js"></script>


<!-- DataTables JS -->
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.6/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.7.1/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.6/js/dataTables.bootstrap5.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.7.1/js/buttons.bootstrap5.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.2.2/jszip.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.7.1/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/2.3.6/js/buttons.colVis.min.js"></script>


<select class="form-select" id="selectMySearch" data-placeholder="Recherches enregistrées ">
  <option></option>
  <option>Test1</option>
  <option>Test2</option>
</select>



Note: Added CSS with !important to just showcase you the issue and solution. You need to remove that CSS rule or atleast change the value to unset
